# Como mover elemento aleatoriamente pela tela (css ou jquery)?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Como fazer um elemento movimentar-se pela tela de maneira aleatória quicando nas bordas da tela. Tipo aqueles protetores de tela de aparelhos DVDs antigos?!?

O exemplo mais próximo que achei a minha pergunta foi em css (keyframes, transforms, animations,etc...) más torna o código muito extenso pois precisava adicionar "alguns" elementos a mais. [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/subversivo58/cs7tmdo9/).

Se alguém tiver solução equivalente (e menor) em jquery agradeço desde já.

Comment: [Igual a este?](http://jsfiddle.net/Xw29r/)

Comment: Já tinha visto este. Más não, o que procuro flutua pela tela "ricocheteando" quando bate nas bordas da tela.

Comment: Grato pela atenção amigo más, o que procuro o elemento parte em uma trajetória, bate no canto da tela (laterais) e recocheteia seguindo nova trajetória. Sem ter caminho prédetermiado. "Quicando pela tela" tens alguma idéia? PS: não achei nada parecido.

Comment: Há uma discussão similar resolvida no "stackoverflow.com". segue o link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774659/random-movement-in-a-fixed-container

Comment: Não, este é o mesmo exemplo que o @Papa Charlie passou. O que procuro segue um caminho em linha reta, bate no canto da tela (laterais) e recocheteia seguindo nova trajetória. Sem ter caminho prédetermiado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo no [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zrL5qkhh/1/) adaptado como base [**esta resposta**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10234282).

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.bouncer').click( function(){
        alert('clicaram no: ' + $(this).attr('title'));
    });
});

$(function() {
    var minSpeed = .02;
    var maxSpeed = .06;
    var varSpeed = .005;

    function startBounce(element) {
        var container = element.parent();
        var width = container.innerWidth() - element.outerWidth();
        var height = container.innerHeight() - element.outerHeight();

        var vertSpeed = ((Math.random() * (maxSpeed - minSpeed)) + minSpeed);
        var horzSpeed = ((Math.random() * (maxSpeed - minSpeed)) + minSpeed);
        bounce(element, vertSpeed, height, 'top');
        bounce(element, horzSpeed, width, 'left');
    }

    function bounce(element, speed, max, dir) {
        speed += ((Math.random() * varSpeed) - (varSpeed / 2));
        speed = speed < minSpeed ? minSpeed : (speed > maxSpeed ? maxSpeed : speed)
        var time = max / speed;
        var position = element.position();
        if (position[dir] < 2) {
            target = max;
        } else {
            target = 0;
        }

        var style = {
            queue: false
        };
        style[dir] = target;
        element.animate(style, {
            duration: time,
            queue: false,
            easing: "linear",
            complete: function() {
                bounce(element, time, max, dir);
            }
        });
    }

    startBounce($('#bouncer1'));
    startBounce($('#bouncer2'));
});
```

**CSS**

```
#container{position:absolute; width:300px; height:200px}
.bouncer{position:absolute; width:20px; height:20px;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="bouncer" id="bouncer1" title="bouncer 1">•</div>
    <div class="bouncer" id="bouncer2" title="bouncer 2">•</div>
</div>
```

---

*Estou mantendo o código fonte aqui como garantia, pois q questão original no SOEN foi dada como duplicata de uma questão que já foi removida.*

Comment: Grato! Esta mais fluído do que o exemplo que tinha achado...não abusando de sua paciência. Como poderia inserir mais "bouncers" e com pontos de partida diferentes? No css seu que tem como reaproveitar o código agrupando classes (ids) más e no jquery?

Comment: Não sei qual aplicação que vai fazer mas se você colocar `startBounce($('#bouncer')); startBounce($('#bouncer2'));` nai ter 2 bouncer rodando aleatórios.

Comment: A aplicação seriam alguns "bouncers" (4 ou 5) tentarei usar valores "clicaveis" neles...por isso pus o <a> no exemplo.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta 2 bouncer's e evento click em cada um, incremente conforme sua necessidade.

Comment: Sem palavras. Grato pela atenção e pela grande ajuda!

Comment: Disponha. Foi um exemplo adaptado; você pode reescrever melhor esse código depois.